# AngularJS backend call and response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, request, response, backend

I am learning AngularJS. I gone through the back-end calling and response functionality in former.I got confused.So if you guys, can explain me, how to send a request to server,its different ways and how to get response from server in our AngularJS it will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Rajesh Choudhary

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

to know about how to work on backed calling in angular js.. you should have to know about...[promises in js](https://www.promisejs.org/) after that its easy to get about remaining things

Answer (score 0):

You can make a call to the server via the `$http` service. Here is some code to get started:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$http',  function ($http) {
self = this;

self.makeCall = function (url) {
    $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        // Do something with your data
    }).error(function(er) {
        // Do something with your error
    });
  }
}]);
```

This is the shortcut version. Basically you call the url and get a success or error promise back where you can deal with the data/error.  Read more about it at [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)